# How to find eigenvector of large matrix without substitution directly.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

\begin{bmatrix}a&b&b&0&0&0\\b&a&b&0&0&0\\b&b&a&0&0&0\\0&0&0&a&b&b\\0&0&0&b&a&b\\0&0&0&b&b&a\end{bmatrix}

I have a large matrix as above which I already know that

\begin{bmatrix}a&b&b\\b&a&b\\b&b&a\end{bmatrix} have three eigenvectors equal to \begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix} and \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}

Is there any way I can find eigenvector for a large matrix above by using the submatrix that I already solved

Thank you 
ps. If you found this question is a duplicate of another, kindly put the link for me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure: $$\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\1\\-1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix},$$ $$\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\0\\-1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},$$ and $$\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: can you explain it more please, actually I was thinking that the answer will be like this but I don't know the method

Comment: actually,  any combination (one over the other) of the 3D vectors will provide a 6D eigenvector

Comment: that's because the blocks in the matrix are separated, they operate over a distinct sub-space, for each of which you can have one of the 3D vector3

Comment: @user2092391 Your matrix is of the type $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}A&0\\0&A\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. If $A.v=\lambda v$, then the product of your matrix by $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}v\\v\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ is $\lambda\left(\begin{smallmatrix}v\\v\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.

Comment: @GCab Some combinations won't work, because over their respective subspaces a different eigenvalue is produced

Comment: @B.Mehta: you are fully right: my mistake

Comment: @user2092391 what if I change it to \left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&A\\A&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)
then can I say that it will produce the same eigenvectors?

Comment: @user2092391 I am not entirely sure about what you are asking. If the question is: “Are the vectors from your answer eigenvectors for the new matrix?”, then, yes, they are.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: What happens when you apply your matrix to this vector?
$$\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\1\\0\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$$
Can you generalise this idea to find 6 eigenvectors? Are they linearly independent?

Comment: yes they are linearly dependent 

but I am still confusing

Comment: Observe that the vector I gave is an eigenvector, and modify it to give 6 eigenvectors

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable as $A=MD_AM^{-1}$ and $B=ND_BN^{-1}$ ( where the columns of $M$ are the eigenvectors of $A$ and the columns of $N$ are the eigenvectors of $B$) than we have:

$$
C=\begin{pmatrix}A&0\\0&B
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}MD_AM^{-1}&0\\0&ND_BN^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}=
$$
$$
=\begin{pmatrix}M&0\\0&N
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}D_A&0\\0&D_B
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}M^{-1}&0\\0&N^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}M&0\\0&N
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}D_A&0\\0&D_B
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}M&0\\0&N
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
$$
So $C$ is diagonalizable as 
$$
C=PDP^{-1}
$$

and the columns of $P=\begin{pmatrix}M&0\\0&N
\end{pmatrix}$ are the eigenvectors of $C$.

Comment: Thank you u guys for answering my question, I've got the idea from u guys a lot